# jQuery Make item 'flash' when clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have the following code:

```
        <style>
.submit input, .submit a
{
   border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;
   background: #b2d4eb;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#9ebbce), to(#b2d4eb));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #9ebbce, #b2d4eb);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #9ebbce, #b2d4eb);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #9ebbce, #b2d4eb);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #9ebbce, #b2d4eb);
   padding: 5px 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: black;
}

.submitHighlight
{
    background: #FFFF99;    
}

.BtnSmall
{
    width: 15em;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 1em; 
    display: none;
}
</style>

    <script language="JavaScript" src="..\Generic\JAVASCRIPT\jQuery-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="..\Generic\JAVASCRIPT\jQuery-ui-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#SG1").click(function()
            {
                $(this).parent().switchClass('submit','submitHighlight','slow').delay(2000).switchClass('submitHighlight','submit','slow');
            })  
    })

    </script>

    <p class="submit">
        <input id="SG1" class="BtnSmall" type="submit" name="submit" value="SG1" style="display: inline-block;">
    </p>
```

What I am trying to do is get it so that when I click the button, it 'flashes' from the original blue to yellow and back again to highlight the fact it was pressed.

The closest I have got so far is with the above code, but that is far from a 'flash', more a stutter.

What would be the best way to go about this?

I tried to use animate, but couldn't see how to animate an add /remove class.

Comment: Not related to the question being asked, I wonder why you need a `submit` button inside a `<p>`...

Comment: good question - no reason that I can remember, but not being a programmer by trade (more a DBA), it is one of (probably many) bad habits I have picked up over the years. Most of my code is normally cut and paste from older projects, and then 'improved' on.

Comment: You want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zr460dqa/) or by flash did you mean something else..?

Comment: by 'flash' it is basically just something to alert the user that the button has been pressed (or when I convert it to my actual script - that the button has appeared). This certainly is a step up from my effort. cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9kv7Lkt/1/)

You dont have have the basic style rules of the input set for your second class, so when the class is switched you lose the things like padding, box-shadow, etc.

I rearranged your style rules to more explicitly do things ( note I left your border on the yellow one because I don't know what you want to do with it).

```
#SG1 {
    padding: 5px 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: black;   
}
.submit #SG1
{
   border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;
   background: #b2d4eb;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#9ebbce), to(#b2d4eb));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #9ebbce, #b2d4eb);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #9ebbce, #b2d4eb);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #9ebbce, #b2d4eb);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #9ebbce, #b2d4eb);
}

.submitHighlight #SG1
{
    background: #FFFF99;
}

.BtnSmall
{
    width: 15em;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 1em; 
    display: none;
}
```

You can add in some css transitions as well to smooth out the color change if youre feeling frisky.
then you would have an initial #SG1 style rules of something like this:

```
#SG1 {
    padding: 5px 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: black;  
   transition: background 1s ease; 
}
```

Comment: cheers, that looks good. Something urgent came up, but I'll take a closer look tomorrow hopeefully.